# Windows 10/Edge pinned site tiles - caching/refreshing and inaccurate tile color rendering

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

Not sure if this is an Edge or more general Windows 10 question, but trying to get pinned site tile to work I'm encountering some rather strange behavior.

First of all, are application tile images cached aggressively? It seems that once a site was pinned, changes to the relevant meta elements seem to be ignored. Un-pinning, clearing browser cache and doing a Windows clean-up of temp files/temp internet files has no effect. Even completely removing the meta elements, then trying to pin the site, still reuses the old ones. This makes debugging/testing rather difficult. Is there something I'm missing? How can the tile information be flushed?

Secondly, it seems that the specified `msapplication-TileColor` is not handled correctly - in the example below I'm using transparent PNG files for the icons themselves, setting a tile color

```xml
<meta name="application-name" content="The Paciello Group (TPG)"> 
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#1b75bc"> 
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/images/tpg-white-trans-144.png">
<meta name="msapplication-square70x70logo" content="/images/tpg-white-trans-70.png">
<meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="/images/tpg-white-trans-150.png">
<meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="/images/tpg-white-trans-310.png">
```

However, checking the color that's actually used, it seems to be closer to #2672EC than #1b75bc. Could this be because of some color profile issue? Could it be that color profile information in the PNG is affecting the rendering of the actual specific tile color?

[image: Although the tile color nominally matches the blue of the site, it's rendered differently]

[image: Same inaccurate color rendering on mobile]

Comment: if you try to view the problem on the live site http://www.paciellogroup.com I've since tried to strip any color profile info etc from the PNGs with pngcrush. However, due to the caching issue, I can't verify if my hypothesis (that the tile color is adjusted to the color profile of the tile image) is correct / if this solves the problem.

Comment: Looks like #2672EC is the Edge background colour. Seems to be ignoring whatever is added to msapplication-TileColor

Answer (score 3):

They messed up, first Windows 10 release it was taking msapplication-tilecolor, after first mass update around 5th of August, they took away tilecolor as well, made it default blue (or whatever user preferences are)

We also need text color as well

Answer (score 1):

> First of all, are application tile images cached aggressively?

Yes, remote tile images are cached, and they're cached separately from the normal internet cache. To update an image without changing the URL, you have to add a new query string parameter, so that it's considered a new URL.

> How can the tile information be flushed?

The cached entries are stored in the registry at...

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications\wpnidm`

You probably can find the related image cache entry and delete it for debugging purposes, but I won't make any promises.

> Secondly, it seems that specified msapplication-TileColor is not handled correctly

Looks like [SiSL has your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976793/1454643) for that: "They messed up, first Windows 10 release it was taking msapplication-tilecolor, after first mass update around 5th of August, they took away tilecolor as well, made it default blue (or whatever user preferences are)"

Answer (score 0):

I found the cache path!

Go to a path similar to this: "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\PinnedTiles".

The folder "Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe" might have a bit different name.

The cached files (Images, XML...) of the tiles you pinned will be inside the folders in this path.

Delete as much as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is about the color, though. I've been testing this MSTiles feature recently and it looks like on Win10 it now uses one of the icons you set for the website (for me it seems to utilize largest icon from webmanifest). It completely ignores what I write in metatags of browserconfig.xml file for icons, as well (square* and wide* elements), which seems to result in the fact I can only set tile's size to small or medium.